# Adding a custom image upload size and making it selected by default?

Tags: php, uploads, media, images

How can I add a custom image upload size with a width of 550px and make it selected by default in the Add Media page?

Currently, there are 4 sizes available: `Thumbnail`, `Medium`, `Large` and `Full Size`. The `Full Size` option is selected by default.

Anyone knows a working solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few steps to this, as I found out today. First, you add a custom image size (you can put this somewhere the `functions.php` file in your theme):

```php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'my-size', 550, 550 ); // not sure what you want your height to
                                     // be, but this'll shrink it to 550px
                                     // wide *or* tall. If you want it to be
                                     // cropped to a 550px square, add true as
                                     // a fourth argument
```

The unfortunate thing is that WordPress doesn't actually show this new size in the media uploader. You'll have to put a function that does this into your `functions.php` as well (source: http://kucrut.org/insert-image-with-custom-size-into-post/):

```php
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // get the custom image sizes
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    // if there are none, just return the built-in sizes
    if ( empty( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
        return $sizes;

    // add all the custom sizes to the built-in sizes
    foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
        // take the size ID (e.g., 'my-name'), replace hyphens with spaces,
        // and capitalise the first letter of each word
        if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
            $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
    }

    return $sizes;
}

// apply the above function as a filter on the media uploader's list of
// image sizes
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
```

Lastly, to set this size as the default, you'll need to change a WordPress setting. Add a filter on the setting in question. This has the benefit of being portable with your theme in which you've defined all the above options.

```
function my_set_default_image_size () {
    return 'my-size';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'my_set_default_image_size' );
```

I tested this all out on WordPress 3.4.2, and it seems to work great.

Note: I'd recommend putting the above PHP code into an init function of some sort and attaching it to the `'after_setup_theme'` hook:

```php
// define the functions first
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // not going to repeat the function body, for brevity's sake
}

function my_set_default_image_size() {
    // ditto
}

// define the init function next, which sets up all the necessary stuff
function custom_image_setup () {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'my-size', 550, 550 );
    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'my_set_default_image_size' );
}

// and attach that init function to the 'after_setup_theme' hook
// so it runs on each page load once your theme's been loaded
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_image_setup' );
```

Comment: No need for the SQL, you can use the `pre_option_{$option_name}` filter.  Eg. `add_filter('pre_option_image_default_size', function() { return 'my-size'; });`

Comment: @chrisguitarguy: thanks for the tip; I didn't know about that and have updated my answer accordingly. This has the added benefit of being more portable.

Comment: there is no function needed to set the default image size to a custom value: `update_option('image_default_size', 'my-size' );` does the trick. but this only works with your `my_insert_custom_image_sizes` function, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set all other options to `0` in your Admin panel under "Settings" » "Media". This will disable them.

Comment: This did not answer my question, unless if I am confused. I asked: How can I add a custom image upload size with a width of 550px and make it selected by default in the Add Media page?

Comment: Add a custom image size (see Codex) and then set all default ones to `0`. That does answer your question.

Comment: No but then the Full Size one will be selected by default. As I am sure that you already know, I cannot remove Full Size from the list and I do not want to either. How can I make so that my custom sized one is selected by default and not Full Size?

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand your needs.

Comment: Do you know a solution to it buddy?

Comment: Aside from that I don't feel like a "buddy", sorry, but no. Not out of my head. Afaik there have been answers about those media box filters, but I don't know it right now. Anyway. The UI will have massive changes with upcoming 3.5, so I'm not too sure, if the answer will help anyone in a couple of weeks too. You'll also have to check out the Nightly builds. Dominik Schilling/Ocean90 and Helen Housandi are working on it right now.